# drop1 function does not show correct statistics

Tags: r

I am trying to run some simple hypothesis tests with the drop1 function in R.

```
lmer1 <- lmer(Liking ~ Order + Cooking + Insect + (1|Child) + (1|Group), data=insectData)
stats::drop1(lmer1, test="Chisq")

Single term deletions using Satterthwaite's method:

Model:
Liking ~ Order + Cooking + Insect + (1 | Child) + (1 | Group)
         Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
Order   20.8086 20.8086     1 125.83  24.797 2.053e-06 ***
Cooking  0.1611  0.1611     1 126.03   0.192  0.661982    
Insect   8.6526  8.6526     1 125.80  10.311  0.001679 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I don't understand why it does not show the likelihood ratio test statistic, even though I tried to specify it. It seems like it is using the F-test instead? Can anyone spot what is wrong?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I don't quite understand why that's happening. I tried something similar to you but got the likelihood ratio test as intended. Can you please give more information so that we can reproduce your result? Please provide a small example of your data using `dput()` and information on the version of R and lme4 that you have on your machine.

Comment: I solved it with the help of a friend by declaring `lme4::lmer` in the model definition. Somehow I think the wrong lmer function was called, which is super strange... So it was a model problem, not a `drop1` problem.

Comment: It may be that you had the `lmerTest` package loaded after `lme4`. This will mask the `lme4::lmer()` function with a different one that may not have all the same methods defined for the base `stats` functions like `drop1()`.

Comment: FYI in future if you provide the full code needed to reproduce your issue on someone else's machine in your original question (including all `library()` calls in the R session) that will make it much easier for someone on this site to diagnose your problem and help you solve it.